# Applying textures to a plane game object results in spreading

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

As visible in the attached image, when I apply a grass or ground texture to a plane, it all spreads around and looks like it is being stretched to fill the whole floor...

I cannot seem to find any settings that would address this. I have already triedx setting the wrap mode to repeat, according to this manual [page](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureWrapMode.html)...

Could someone please help me understand why this is caused and how I can fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shader options you can change tiling on the X and Y direction. Greater tiling means more repeats of the texture on the plane. Tiling is defaulted to 1 when dragging a texture on which explains the stretched out look you got. For a fairly large plane try 100 by 100 or whatever fits.

To open the shader settings for the material you are using, select Forest Floor inside the inspector panel.

Comment: Thanks John. When I search for Forest Floor, I get a texture and a material. In the material, I can see the shader options, of which I change the X and Y tiling to 100, for example. But dragging neither the texture nor the material into the scene changes my plane's texture. Is this what you meant? Am I missing a step, or did I not understand you correctly?

Comment: An easier way to get to the menu would be to click on the plane object as you did, and on the panel named Inspector (on the right side of the screen) clicking the last row. This opens a menu similar to this one: http://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/Inspector-MaterialSimple.png Afterwards, changing the tiling should make the plane texture repeat. Verify that you are changing the first tiling options (there are two, one under main maps and another under secondary maps). Are you changing this option: http://i.imgur.com/BlAdBsS.png

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool on the asset store, the "Auto Texture Tiling Tool", which automates the process and has a ton of features for applying and tiling textures. It is way more useful than the Tile settings on materials. Since it is independent from shaders and materials, you can use the same materials with different tiling settings. Check it out here: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/auto-texture-tiling-tool-41613

Comment: Welcome to SO. This answer does not provide a solution to the problem specified.